# How to check View Source in Mobile Browsers (Both Android && Feature Phone)

Tags: html, browser, view-source

I need to check the view source of the page from mobile / tablet browsers ( Android Phones/Tablets and Feature Phones).

I tried some of the methods but is not feasible like in desktop. I feels difficult to check it.

### JS

```
javascript: alert(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);
```

### Chrome && Firefox (Android)

```
view-source:http://domain.com
```

Is it there any other method to check in other browsers and in featured phone browsers

Comment: May be useful for your question

[http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-view-source-in-the-android-browser](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-do-i-view-source-in-the-android-browser).

Comment: @prakashstar42 I checked this but not mentioned about how to check in feature phone browsers and other browsers

Answer (score 20):

Now, adding `view-source:` before the **site-address.com** works on Chrome - Android.
Source: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-view-a-webpage-source-code-in-Google-chrome-mobile-version

Answer (score 3):

The view-source url prefix trick didn't work for me using chrome on an iphone. There are apps I could have installed to do this I guess but for whatever reason I just preferred to do it myself rather than install 'yet another app'.

I found this nice quick tutorial for how to setup a bookmark on mobile safari that will automatically open the view source of a page: https://appletoolbox.com/2014/03/how-to-view-webpage-html-source-codes-on-ipad-iphone-no-app-required/

It worked flawlessly for me and now I have it set as a permanent bookmark any time I want, with no app installed.

Edit: There are basically 6 steps which should work for either Chrome or Safari. Instructions for Safari are:

1. Open Safari and browse to an arbitrary page.
2. Select the "Share" (or action") button in Safari (looks like a square with an arrow coming out of the top).
3. Select "Add Bookmark"
4. Delete the page title and replace it with something useful like "Show Page Source". Click Save.
5. Next browse to this exact Stack Overflow answer on your phone and copy the javascript code below to your phone clipboard (code credit: Rob Flaherty):

```
javascript:(function(){var a=window.open('about:blank').document;a.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Source of '+location.href+'</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" /></head><body></body></html>');a.close();var b=a.body.appendChild(a.createElement('pre'));b.style.overflow='auto';b.style.whiteSpace='pre-wrap';b.appendChild(a.createTextNode(document.documentElement.innerHTML))})();
```

6. Open the "Bookmarks" in Safari and opt to Edit the newly created Show Page Source bookmark. Delete whatever was previously saved in the Address field and instead paste in the Javascript code. Save it.
7. (Optional) Profit!

Comment: The reason this doesn't work in Chrome on the iPhone is that, on the iPhone, the Chrome app is effectively just a wrapper around Safari. So is Firefox, and and any other browser app. Apple doesn't permit apps to bring their own HTML renderer, so on a non-jailbroken iOS device, all restaurants are Taco Bell.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this cool app available in play store called Html Page Source
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scintillar.hps

Answer (score 2):

This question is a few years old, and there are some good suggestions for workarounds, but I didn't really notice any answers that address the core of the original question head-on. So:

- Providing a "universal" method for viewing source in a feature phone browser (or even arbitrary third-party smartphone browser) is impossible because "view source" — via any method — is a feature implemented in the browser. So how it's accessed, or even if it *can* be accessed, is up to the developers of the browser. I'm sure there are plenty of browsers that intentionally prevent the user from viewing page source, and if so then you're out of luck, except maybe for workarounds like the ones offered here.
- Workarounds such as "view source" apps **external** to the browser, while useful in some cases, are at best an imperfect partial solution to the original request. It's never certain that any such app will display the source of the page *in the same form* as it's loaded by the phone's browser.

  Modern web content changes itself in all manner of ways through browser detection, session management, etc. so that the source loaded by any external app can never be relied on to represent the source as loaded by a different app. If you're going to use an external app to load a page because you want to see the source, you might as well just use Chrome (or, on an iOS device, Safari) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but still a problem within the Chrome dev tools. I find the best way to check mobile source locally is to open the site locally in Xcode's iOS Simulator. Then from there you open the Safari browser and enable dev tools, if you have not already done this (go to preferences -> advanced -> show develop menu in menu bar). Now you will see the develop option in the main menu and can go to develop -> iOS Simulator -> and the page you have open in Xcode's iOS Simulator will be there. Once you click on it, it will open the web inspector and you can edit as you would normally in the browser dev tools.

I'm afraid this solution will only work on a Mac though as it uses Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with JavaScript bookmark code isn’t formatted and it’s very important on mobile.

Use https://view-source.hellafast.digital

It’s a web based solution and it also can be integrated to iOS

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29875512)

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions where not accurate enough for me. The webpage I'm trying to access is dynamically loaded. Using view-source does not give me the full code and the JavaScript method does not display the full code.

Here is the solution I found for Google Chrome on Android:

- Click "More"
- Click "Download"
- Open a file explorer app
- Rename the downloaded file and add the `.txt` extension
- Open the file like a regular file