# How to see the html code if the app using WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I found a beautiful android app and I want to see the source code
I know the app is using webview to develop

Comment: so what do you want to us to on this problem

Comment: I want to get the html code for that webview

Comment: Go to the site with a computer. Press F12 et voila?

Comment: I think the question can be rephrased to read "**How can you see the source of an android webview?**" or possibly "**How can you find the site that a webview is pointing to?**" Both legitimate questions that are probably already answered.

Comment: I want to see the current displaying on my app webview of source code, because there are some form data that I also want to see but if I use chrome on my computer, the data is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your phone via usb to a computer and use [a browser's remote debugging tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/), you can see where the webview is pointing to.

Then you can just go there in that browser and look at the source.

If you want to see the code as a mobile device sees it, you can also use:

```
view-source:http://domain.com
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905940/how-to-check-view-source-in-mobile-browsers-both-android-feature-phone))

Comment: [link](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)

Comment: [here link is I want](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews)    but the app is others so I cant add the code for debugging. What should i do?

Comment: or can I just see what is the web link for that webview?

Comment: correct, you shouldnt have to add code to see where the webview is pointing if you're remote debugging